# SQL Server 2016 on EC2 : How to add the Named Instance ?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We're planning to develop AWS EC2 Intance by SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition AMI for our system replace.
Current SQL Server 2012 has two instance, default instance 'MSSQLSERVER' and named instance.

On EC2, we understand default instance 'MSSQLSERVER' will be installed by AMI.
But not sure how we can add the named instance, since we don't have any install media by ourselves this time as it's not BYOL(Except for evaluation).

I notice we can set the number of instances at EC2 launch, NO3 process in following link. 
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4389/launch-sql-server-instances-on-amazon-ec2/

May I ask does that mean we can have two instances, default MSSQLSERVER and named instance, by this setting?

Any advice or your experience would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that the The AWS usage of the word "instance" refers to the host, not the SQL Server instance. Having said that... why do you need a named instance? Just use two seperate servers.

Comment: or to put it another way... are you trying to create a named instance _purely_ because you currently have a named instance? Don't bother, just create anothe seperate server. You're going to have to update client connection details anyway

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Thanks for your comment, Nick. I understand your question-- I understand separate EC2 instance would be more ideal. Why we need the named instance is, due to our customer's budget. We can not afford two EC2 server at this stage... And named instance is exclusively for our BI Meta Data.

Comment: It seems like your second instance would be a very low powered server. Or is the licencing the cost? SQL Express 2017 (free for commercial use) supports 10G and four cores. If it's just a metadata database then you could get a minimally spec'd server (say 1-2 cores a 8G RAM)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Many thanks again Nick. Oh, that's great information for us! May I ask AIM ID if you know? As your detection, it could be enough for our BI metadata database. We're just concerned about the licence cost and then consider two instances in one EC2 instance.

Comment: I googled "AWS AMI SQL Express" and got this: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B06XZYFLRD

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I really appreciated all of your kind advice. Your timely information helps us a lot. Have a wonderful day, Nick.

Comment: Great to hear. Good luck with that. I still don’t know why this was split into two instances in the first place but it sounds like you have your solution.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Yeah, you're right again. Exclusive instance is maker's recommendation but we started to think we can have it all in one instance. So, first we'll try single instance and if some issue is coming, then we will try reasonable AMI, you kindly let me know here.